# My internal "Machintosh HD" is not detected by my MacBook Air

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, install, startup

I was trying to clean install OS X (from http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-clean-install-os-x-yosemite-via-bootable-usb-flash-drive-1470625).

I made the bootable disk, booted from it, and tried installing. Something happened and installation began. I went out for 20 mins and when I returned, I saw the installation welcome screen again. Proceeding on which I found that it came to installing it once again, but this time the internal Macintosh HD was not showing only the USB (Install OS X Yose..) was shown.

What to do? Where did my HDD go? any help?

Comment: Also when looking at the command they have missed the quotations and/or "\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replacing the SSD and started it.

I pressed the keys combination of Internet Recovery and it worked. My Macbook is now working fine with El Caption installed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try and format the disk by using Disk Utility built into the installer (Utility > Disk Utility) then try and reinstall.

This should work since 'Macintosh HD' is only a volume and not the actual SSD. I used this method to fix the b-node tree error or whatever it is where I couldn't write to it.

This worked

Answer (score 1):

Try and format the disk by using Disk Utility built into the installer (Utility > Disk Utility) then try and reinstall.

This should work since 'Macintosh HD' is only a volume and not the actual SSD. I used this method to fix the `b-node tree error` or whatever it is where I couldn't write to it.

Comment: I can not actually find that in Disk Utility. The only thing I can see in disk utility is the USB stick (from which the Mac OS X installer ran).

Comment: Can you give a screenshot please?

Comment: Also try using GParted.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I will give you a screenshot as soon I get to my office.

Comment: @KumarRavi Cant see the screen shot yet :p. Also send me the output of this command (do it in terminal) `diskutil list`